# C# check Lua script before executing

Tags: c#, lua

I have recently implemented lua scripting in my project, and it is possible for users to enter their custom scripts in the game editor, but here's the problem... they can easily enter some random stuff and the program will die with exception...

So my question: is it possible to *check* lua script before executing it? And preferably point to exact place where entered script is incorrect.

I know I can add "try" block, but it's not the best solution imo.

Upd: As was requested in comments: I'm using "LuaInterface" build for NET 4.

Comment: You might want to get familiar with exception handling. You miss many important information in your question, like what kind of library do you use for lua scripting, so I can't tell you anything specific (also I'm not familiar with the technology, just googled some). I would guess if you catch an exception, it will provide some additional information about what caused it, maybe even the exact location.

Comment: Also exception handling is one of the many advantages in OO programming, you can spare yourself a lot of headache by utilising it correctly.

Comment: @Robert hm... but how can I know what exactly was wrong in the script from catching an exception? I was hoping for something like "evaluate script before executing" thing :)

Comment: The exception you catch is an object. You can check its properties, probably it has information on what caused it. But meanwhile I see Mud solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [error handling](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.3) in the manual, specifically [`lua_load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_load). That'll catch compile time errors. Then see [`lua_pcall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pcall) and perhaps [`luaL_traceback`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_traceback) for handling runtime errors.

Comment: Oh, great! That is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Do note that `lua_load` only checks for syntax errors. It can't ensure that the script will execute without causing any trouble, as that is impossible. Also, if you want to check a script outside of a program, you can use `luac` to check syntax; `luac -p <file>` and `luac -t <file>` will perform syntax checking and integrity checking, respectively.